# Looking to print all possible solutions

Tags: java

I'm working on a program similar to the **NQueens** problem but using **Bishops** instead of Queens.The expected output should be all the possible solutions.

```
   public class Bishops {


    static int n;
    static int count = 1;


    private static boolean isSafe(char matrix[][], int row, int col)
    {


        for (int i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--)
            if (matrix[i][j] == 'B')
                return false;


        for (int i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j < n; i--, j++)
            if (matrix[i][j] == 'B')
                return false;


        return true;
    }

    private static void bish(char matrix[][], int row)
    {
        if (row == n)
        {
            System.out.println(count++);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    System.out.print(matrix[j][i] + " ");                       
                System.out.println();    
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(count++);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");                       
                System.out.println();    
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (isSafe(matrix, row, i)){
                matrix[row][i] = 'B';
                bish(matrix, row + 1);
                matrix[row][i] = '*';
            }

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );

     System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
      n = sc.nextInt();
        char[][] matrix = new char[n][n];


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            Arrays.fill(matrix[i], '*');
        }


        bish(matrix, 0);

    }

}
```

My outputs for when I enter two returns four solutions which is correct, however when I enter three it only returns ten solutions when it should be twenty six. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you still trying to solve this?

Comment: Yeah didn't end up getting it to work properly.